# Replace values in a string - PHP

Tags: php

I have a string 'some value' and I am looking for the function that replaces certain values with another one.

For example I need the

> 'some value'

to become

> 'some_value'

This is what I have tried so far with no luck

```
  $newCategory=str_replace(' ', '_', $rows["category"]); 
  echo $newCategory;
```

Comment: Yes its working fine , may be you are doing some mistake. http://ideone.com/65V2lA

Comment: wha'st wrong with above code ?

Comment: it doesn't want to output 'some_value' for some reason with no errors

Comment: i'm an idiot... i had an extra `echo` before `$newCategory=str_replace(' ', '_', $rows["category"]);`

Comment: residual code from my previews version i guess :)

Comment: Best of luck and always go through at least one time on your code for some minor issues.sometimes it happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works fine for me

```
$rows["category"] =  'some value';
$newCategory=str_replace(' ', '_', $rows["category"]); 
echo $newCategory;
```

Output

> some_value

Display errors could be turned off in the php.ini or your apache config file.

You can turn it on in the script and see any error is there

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I had an extra echo before my code... :( I will accept your answer in 5 mins.

Comment: Welcome @Geo. Enjoy coding.:-)

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me. Still you can give this a try:

```
$newCategory = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $rows["category"]);
```